# Pandas - check for series value in another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check whether the string value in one dataframe column is contained in another dataframe column. My dataframe is:

```
d = {'col1': ['Live', 'Live','Live','Deferrred'], 'col2': ['Live', 'Not live,Deferred', 'Deferred,Live','Not live']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

```
        col1               col2
0       Live               Live
1       Live  Not live,Deferred
2       Live      Deferred,Live
3  Deferrred           Not live
```

A new column 'Check' should show True if the value in Col1 is one of the separated values in Col2 such that:

```
        col1               col2 Check
0       Live               Live     Y
1       Live  Not live,Deferred     N
2       Live      Deferred,Live     Y
3  Deferrred           Not live     N
```

I have tried:

```
conditions = [df['col1'].isin(df['col2'])]
choices = [('Y')]
df['Check'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default = 'N')
```

However this returns `True` for `Live in Not live` whereas it should return `False`.

I have also tried:

```
conditions = [df['col2'].contains(df['col1'])]
```

however this returned:
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'`

Is there a way to make `.isin()` case sensitive or is there another way to make `Live in Not live` return `False`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can do:

```
df['Check'] = (df
              .apply(lambda x: 'Y' if x['col1'] in x['col2'] else 'N', 1))
```

Comment: with that lambda I think you could modify it to be `lambda x: 'Y' if x['col1'] in x['col2'] else 'N'` and get rid of the call to replace.

Comment: Possible edge case where Live is a substring of some phrase in col2, like col1 = 'Live' and col2 = 'Not Live, Deferred'. Even safer would be `lambda x: 'Y' if x['col1'] in x['col2'].split(',') else 'N'` but OP didn't demonstrate that that's a possible enumeration so it might be moot.

Comment: This works for now, but replace `Not live` with `Not Live` and you will see that this will give the wrong result

Comment: yes I saw that too, but the OP question doesn't seem to mention such cases.

Comment: I'm going with this answer, as it works and despite using pandas quite a lot, have never bitten the bullet to learn .apply. I will now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

df['Check']=np.bitwise_and( df['col2'].str.split(",").map(set), df['col1'].str.split().map(set) ).ne(set())
```

Output:

```py
        col1               col2  Check
0       Live               Live   True
1       Live  Not live,Deferred  False
2       Live      Deferred,Live   True
3  Deferrred           Not live  False
```